# Edit box autofill does not clear placeholder

Tags: php, html, css, edit, osclass

Basic HTML PHP CSS. I have an edit box with a placeholder.  In the case that I have edited the fields once before (like username and password), and the browser has cached them, and I return to the form again (e.g., the login page), both the placeholder text and the auto filled values are appearing over top of each other.  This is using the osclass code, if that matters. Clicking in the edit box removes the placeholder text, and the auto-filled value remains.

Thanks for the help!

Here's the site -
[letmeborrowthat](https://www.letmeborrowthat.com)

[image: placeholder text and edit text both appearing]

Comment: Give **autocomplete="off"** in your text fields. By giving this the autofill will be avoided.

Comment: If you want autofill not need to give the autocomplete. Please post your code to check.

Comment: Do post your code, images won't help troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn the autocomplete off in your code

i.e.,

```
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" class="input-text" autocomplete="off">
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" class="input-text" autocomplete="off">
```

You can read it from the mdn [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Comment: Seems like a severe limitation that they cannot coexist.  The autofilled value should just cause the placeholder to disappear.  Pretty lame.